# apache redirects automatically to https when virtualhost is configured on port 80

Tags: apache, http, https, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I have one apache server with one SSL-certificate installed, and I set up these virtualhosts in the httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  subdomanin.DOMAIN_A.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName  DOMAIN_A.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateKeyFile XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   SSLCertificateFile XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   SSLCertificateChainFile XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
</VirtualHost>
```

Everytime I try to reach http://subdomain.DOMAIN_A.com with my browser, it redirects me to port 443, with https before the address. The certificate doesn't work with the subdomain and I receive an error.

I don't understand how to access the subdomain on port 80 by default and not be redirected on port 443.

Comment: There is no reason for the described redirection in this configuration. So probably the reason lies somewhere else, most likely in some application logic or in some dynamic configuration file.

Comment: in that subdomain there is jus an index.php file without some dynamic configuration.

Comment: Dynamic configuration files are hidden, typically...

Comment: there is an empty folder.  nothing more

Comment: You do know what a dynamic configuration file is and how to check if there is a hidden file? Not trying to annoy you, but you do not really answer in a direct way...

Comment: i try with another domain and it works on http . if i reput the  domainA restart https...

Comment: Have a try again clearing your browsers cache or use an "anonymous tab" for a test. We cannot say more, since we have no access to your system. The configuration you posted clearly is _not_ responsible for the redirection.

Comment: i think i find the problem is on MOD_rewrite. if i remove  "Require all granted" on directory it work..i don't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly confirm whether there is any virtual host entry of subdomanin.DOMAIN_A.com in **SSL.conf**
 If there is any then you have to remove it and restart the services

Comment: To be specific you need to check rewrite entry in the virtual host 80

Answer (score 0):

You can test the following:

1- Try to set different documentRoot

2- Restart apache2

3- Clear browsing cache

4- Look at apache log file if there is any error

Comment: one last thing is to check your dns configuration, make sure subdomanin.DOMAIN_A.com and DOMAIN_A.com have the same A record (server ip), I noticed you put sudomanin.... maybe in your dns config you have subdomain.??

Comment: Yes they have the same ip

Comment: subdomain and subdomanin are different  maybe you set subdomain in your DNS config and subdomanin in virtual host ?

Comment: i try with another domain and it works on http . if i reput the  domainA restart https...

Comment: I think you should clear dns cache in your system, if your are using windows, run command prompt as administrator, and Run the following command: `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: i already do .. every time i reput the domainA restart https request... i don't understand why

Comment: You can try this in another laptop? to see where the problem come from server or browser

Comment: server for sure but i don't understand where

Comment: i think i find the problem is on MOD_rewrite. if i remove  "Require all granted" on directory it work..i don't understand why